# Survey JS used in React App using version 17.0.1?

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-dom, surveyjs

I am trying to implement the Survey Creator from Survey JS in my React App. I am a new developer so could you explain how I fix this? I'm currently using Material UI in my app. If I switch to version 16.5.0 of react and react-dom, then material UI says I need a newer version of react and react-dom. Screenshot of issue below. I'm currently on react and react-dom version 17.0.1

[what shows up in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFeai.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue of incompatible dependencies. React `17.0.1` is quite newer, hence all packages have not been updated to this version.
In your case, `material-ui` is suited for this version but not Survey Js. What you can do is keeping `react@16.5.0` `react-dom@16.5.0` and downgrading material's version, `4.11.2` might be good for instance.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am sorry for asking such a simple question- I am brand spanking new to coding. Unfortunately for me, I didn't realize I can't just go around asking a million questions and will be more careful in the future so I don't get banned. >.<

Comment: No problem, once you have understod it, you can tackle every issue like this. Don't forget to mark this issue as resolved :)